# In Objective-C, using Core Data, how to fetch all of the Entity classes and their meta information?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity, nsmanagedobject

I'd like to fetch all the entities I've created and filter all the ones that have a particular parent entity. In the end, I'm looking for a collection of the class names for all of these entities so I can iterate on them.

I couldn't find any info on how I can do this. Is it possible? How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *allEntityNames = [[yourManagedObjectModel.entitiesByName allKeys] allObjects];
```

Gets you an array of all your entity string names, ordered alphabetically.  Just calling `entitiesByName` on your `NSManagedObjectModel` gets you all the meta information you might want too but is very verbose.

If you want you can check for parent entities right in a block by seeing if the entity's parent entity is `NSManagedObject` or one of your subclasses instead, or do it after the block if you want to keep the "`master list`" for a few cases.

```
NSArray *allEntityNames = [[yourManagedObjectModel.entitiesByName keysOfEntriesPassingTest:^BOOL(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop) {
if (hasParent)
        return YES;
else
        return NO;
    }] allObjects];
```